# TideSDK Ti.App restart()

Tags: javascript, html, tidesdk

i cant figure out how o use the tidesdk api. It says on there documentation to use Ti.App and the restart() function but i tried a couple ways with no luck and also tried to imitate how the ti.media.sound is scripted which i have working but i cant figure out the app restart. Thak you in advance.

I have tried multiple variations of making functions and directly using onclick.

```
<script>
function restart(){
    var restart = Ti.App.restart();

}

</script>

onClick="restart()"
onClick="restart(Ti.App.restart())"
```

Heres the documenttion by the way

http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.App

Comment: did you checked that your restart() function is called?

Comment: yea i have the onclick calling the function

Comment: on which element you have onclick

Comment: `Ti.App.restart()` is working on my side. Can you also share your code for the button?

Comment: i stop the music and attempt the application to restart but all the calculations remain in cache <button class="reset" type="reset" onClick="stopBeat(Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.getResourcesDirectory(), 'music.mp3').nativePath());" onClick="Ti.App.restart()" onClick="location.reload()" onClick=" window.location.reload();"  >RESET</button>

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured out the issue, using the type="reset" on the button it would clear the form and not restart the app, so if i put normal button it restartedbut didnt claer form. To fix this problem i simply added a time delay to make it clear form and then restart like so on the button type reset.

```
onClick="setTimeout(function(){Ti.App.restart();}, 1000);"
```

Hope this helps someone in the future

Comment: Why "`type="reset"` on the button" doesn't appear on the question? You must include all the relevant information, e.g.: your code.